# How may I know if Package Control is successfully installed in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, text-editor

I installed sublime text 3, and I wanted to install Package Control. So I run the installation code at the sublime console as it's instructed at the Package control installation webpage. When I run it, I got the `275309` number as result; however I don´t find the package control options when using `ctrl+shift+P`.

How may I know if Package control was installed correctly? Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just found [here](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/upgrade-to-3124-caused-package-control-to-move-into-ignored-packages/23080) and [here](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/solved-package-control-disabled-in-build-3126/23216/2), that for some reason package control was moved to ignored-packages array in settings. So it can be fixed by erasing the package control from that array. To do so you go to `Preferences->Settings` and in the files search for the "ignored-packages" array, then delete package control, save, exit.
It is assumed this happend due a bug in the last update.

Thanks